# Is there a special name for "I - V - i" or "i - V - I" Modulation?

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, chord-theory, modulation

Recently, while listening to contemporary and pop music, I discovered that many song uses an I - V - i or i - V - I modulation. For example, C major to G major to C minor. I want to know whether there is a name for this particular modulation technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call it a **parallel modulation**, since you're modulating to a parallel key. Googling for that term confirmed that this is what they are called, and led me to this video:

Comment: Just want to add here that it is important to note the difference between *modulation* and *progression*. If this is a tonal region with a distinct shift to another tonal region, then we can consider it a modulation. If it merely passes through the chords described above, it is a progression and therefore should be though of a **modal mixture** as opposed to a parallel modulation.

Answer (score 2):

Hardly a modulation, as it goes to major on the last bar, but a piece that's in minor for its entirety but finishes with a tonic major. That's called a Tierce de Picardie. The 'Picardy third'. In the dim and distant past, a lot of serious music used this as an ending, somewhat brightening things up.

Going from major to minor is, I think a lot less common.A couple of examples would be nice.

Comment: Picardy third is even "mandatory" in endings like Im/I7/IV/V7/I, since once you have heard the major 3rd in I7, ending with the minor tonic would sound "disappointing".
For the major to minor progression, well you have a lot of them in Schubert pieces, including simple juxtaposition I/Im. It's a very effective way to come back to a dramatic minor part, symphonists in the 19th century use this a lot. I had been taught this under the name "minorization".